# How to handle name collisions in python dict like object?

Tags: python

I have a use case where I am reading a pickle file and putting the file contents in custom DictLikeObject.

However, one of the file columns is 'copy' and DictLikeObject has copy method, due to which I am not able to get the correct value of that column.

Consider the below code:

```py
class DictLikeObject(dict):

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except AttributeError:
            raise ValueError("Not Found")

    def copy(self):
        pass

row = DictLikeObject()
row['copy'] = 1;
row['state'] = 'completed'

print(getattr(row, 'state'))
completed

print(getattr(row, 'copy'))
<bound method DictObject.copy of {'copy': 1, 'state': 'completed'}>
```

Is there a way I can make sure that `getattr` returns the value of 'copy' attribute, instead of method ?

Comment: Why not name your attribute something else? Also it should be `copy(self)`

Comment: some project where I need to ensure backward compatibility and can't change already written files with 'copy' column

Comment: Sure, you can use `dict.get` for getting `copy` and `completed` check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `dict.get` to get your attributes instead, which will ensure that the keys are searched, and not the attributes of the class. It also obviates the need to define a custom `__getattr__` dunder method

```
print(row.get('copy'))
print(row.get('state'))
```

The output will be

```
1
completed
```

Although if you want to use `getattr`, you can override the [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) instead

```
class DictLikeObject(dict):

    #Overrode getattribute
    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except AttributeError:
            raise ValueError("Not Found")

    def copy(self):
        pass

row = DictLikeObject()
row['copy'] = 1
row['state'] = 'completed'

print(getattr(row, 'state'))
print(getattr(row, 'copy'))
```

The output will be

```
completed
1
```

Comment: @DeepanshuArora Please don't ask for upvotes as that can be considered as [voter fraud](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/12/23/vote-fraud-and-you/).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `dict.copy` for this, else the getattr will return the classmethod of copy which is what you are seeing.

```
print(row.get('state'))    
print(row.get('copy'))
```